# ExpressionEngine comments import to Disqus

Tags: import, comments, expressionengine, disqus

Has anyone tackled importing default ExpressionEngine comments to Disqus? I found this on github but I'm not sure how to use it, or if it will work. http://gist.github.com/202802

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently used this plugin in a pretty big site with a lot of comments:

http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/cx-disqus-comments

Costs some money, but it did the job, and it syncs back to EE FROM disqus, which can be good for SEO (because you can put your Disqus comments on the page without JS).

Comment: I'll add a vote for CS Disqus Comments. I used it on a site with thousands of existing comments and it worked pretty well.

Comment: I too used CS Disqus Comments.

Comment: The new version of Disqus allows comments to be indexed by Google, so the SEO part isn't as relevant anymore.

Answer (score 3):

There is also a free addon which just integrates Disqus comments with Expressionengine - http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/disqus

Answer (score 2):

You can also manually import your EE comments into Disqus. [Here's an article by Ryan Battles](http://ee-spotlight.com/tutorials/importing_expressionengine_comments_into_disqus) that explains how to create a "WXR" XML file using EE tags.

And you'll want to watch out for a few gotchas:

- Make sure there aren't any blank lines at the top of your XML file.
- Convert [ASCII codes](http://www.ascii-code.com/) to plain text.
- Disable javascript email encryption. Go to *Channel Preferences > Comment Posting* Preferences, and set "Automatically turn URLs and email addresses into links?" to "No". You should also disable it on your WYSIWYG editor if you're using one on your comment form.

Disqus recommends doing a test import into a fake URL first to work out all the kinks. They have an [import monitor](http://import.disqus.com) that outputs any problems with your import file.

Answer (score 1):

I actually got the Ruby script to work and it worked very well!

I added some simple comments to the script to help fill in some gaps:
http://gist.github.com/266251